# match data range from file1 with file2

Tags: perl, bash

I have two files, namely file1.txt and file2.txt which contain data as follows:

file1.txt

```
953503-955502
1284493-1286492
2158134-2160133
2564482-2566481
2983742-2985741
4713105-4715104
6259680-6261679
....
```

file2.txt

```
245201276-245202076
245201286-245202086
245201302-245202102
245201323-245202123
245201338-245202138
245201344-245202144
....
```

Both files have more than 3000 data.

In this set, I want to match from the range of data from `file1.txt` within the range of data from `file2.txt` and get the output in a new file.

How can I match the range of data from the files. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: What do you consider a “matching range”? Could you post the expected output for the example input?

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, what do you mean by "within the range"?  In the example you gave, none of the numbers in file 2 are within the range of the numbers in file 1.

Comment: `grep -F file1.txt file2.txt`??

Answer (score 0):

Use diff, its a build in linux command. Very smart

Comment: Sorry.I didn't make my question very clear. let's assume file1 has values: 1-5,3-7,7-12, 5-18, 68-90 and so on. file-2 has values like 1-10, 2-9, 4-15, 70-100, 30-300, and so on. output file will contain those file-1 values which are fall within the range of file-2 values, like output_file: 1-5 1-10, 3-7 2-9, 7-12 4-15, 68-90 30-300. I don't require those values which are not fall within the range of file-2.